# XML attribute validation possibilities

Tags: c#, xml, validation

I have a C# class which I am converting to XML. I have a problem with validation (I could not find anywhere how to do the restrictions). Let me show you an example:

```
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(ElementName="export_szla_db", DataType = "decimal")]
    public decimal myDecimal
    {
        get
        {
            return this.export_szla_dbField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.export_szla_dbField = value;
        }
    }
```

What I want need to do, is to restrict this decimal to max 10 digits with no fractions.

What is the best way how to achieve something like this? Should I use Attributes (if yes, what is the attribute for this), or should I write custom logic which will take care of validation? What is the best practice?

The reason why I need this, is because of XSD schema that I received:

```
<xs:simpleType name="decimal_egesz_tipus">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>Determining Decimal Type. 10 integers and 0 decimal digits can be entered.</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:totalDigits value="10"/>
        <xs:fractionDigits value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Comment: Restrict or Round ?  It's not s string, this is a very strange (rare) requirement. Don't expect much support for it.

Comment: It looks like an XML Schema use case. Are you open to using this technology?

Comment: I have updated my post, so that you understand why I actually need it

Answer (score 0):

You can simply solve this at the C# level, by programming in the body of the get/set that the value is truncated to +/- 9999999999.

Oops, I was tricked in answering a 2 year old question because it was edited 14 minutes ago :-)